# Opening image in Bootsrap modal does not load image src

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery of images and I want to show the image in a modal when a user clicks an anchor tag. The modal is opening as expected, however, the image is not loaded, it seems that the src is not obtained properly. Why and how can I obtain the src of each image and display it in the modal?

Here is where the image is kept and the a tag that opens the modal:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
 <div class="products-single fix">
    <div class="box-img-hover imgBox">
        <!-- <div class="type-lb">
          <p class="sale">Sale</p>
           </div> -->
    <img src="images/img-pro-01.jpg" class="img-fluid " alt="Image">
  <div class="mask-icon">
     <ul class="thumb">
       <li><a class="pop" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-toggle="modal" data-large-src="images/img-pro-01.jpg" title="View"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></li>
                                                            <!-- <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Compare"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i></a></li> -->
                                                            <!-- <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Add to Wishlist"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></a></li> -->
    </ul>
   <a class="cart" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
   </div>
   </div>
      <div class="why-text">
   <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
   <h5> $9.79</h5>
    </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the modal:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Image preview</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <img src="" id="imagepreview" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;" >
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And here is the simple JQuery code:

```
   $(function() {
        $('.pop').on('click', function() {
            $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
            $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
        });     
});
    </script>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `$('.imagepreview')` should be `$('#imagepreview')` This should be closed as typo.

Comment: The image src still does not load. I guess you shouldn't be that quick to downvote

Comment: In your pop click event, you use this to find a child img of the pop element. However, there is no such element. `<a class="pop" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-toggle="modal" data-large-src="images/img-pro-01.jpg" title="View"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>` Try this instead: `$(this).data('large-src'))` or `$(this).data('largesrc'))` I don't remember how jquery handles the dash in data

Answer (score 1):

`.imagepreview`  should be `#imagepreview` because you're trying to look up an ID, not a class.

If it still doesn't load, I wager this is the problem:

```
$(this).find('img').attr('src')
```

I believe you'll find a `console.log()` of `$(this).find('img')` will return something empty, because `$(this)` in this context is `$('.pop')` and `.pop` has no `<img>` children, so you shouldn't use `$(this)` here. As trying to find `img`s inside `.pop` will return nothing.

If you can I would just give `<img src="images/img-pro-01.jpg">` its own ID and refer to it that way.

or, you can just exploit `.pop`'s `data-large-src` attribute and exploit that... as it seems to be the same image.

I recommend using `console.log()` extensively to find assess whether your selectors are finding anything at all